# Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

My code was working perfectly until 3 days ago:

```
library("xml2")
library("rvest")
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)

cDrv <- chrome()

eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
    args = c('--no-sandbox','--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800',"-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:/Sebastian/Proyectos/R/chromedriver.exe")))

remDr<- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567L,platform = "WINDOWS",extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr$open()
```

Now this error appears:

```
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
  (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

but I downloaded Chrome version 81, and is the one that I'm trying to call in this part of the code:

```
"-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:/Sebastian/Proyectos/R/chromedriver.exe"
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have Chrome 81 on the machine. Check your browser version (not chromedriver version). I believe you might have Chrome 80+ but not 81+.

Comment: That's right, my Chrome version is 80+, but I don't know if I can force Chrome to update to 81+, it updated to the last stable version.

Comment: Please downgrade to [Current stable release: ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/) as `ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69` is still a beta version.

Answer (score 0):

download this
[Chrome WebDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/)